# How to automate the mounting of a Samba shared directory ith each reboot (fstab already created)

Tags: mount, samba, reboot

I have two Linux/Ubuntu boxes.

- Box A (192.168.1.10): works as a file server, with Samba installed. It's always switched on.
- Box B: workstation with my office tools, which I reboot each time I need to work with it.

In Box B, I have '/etc/fstab' modified:

```
//192.168.1.10/SambaSharedDirectory /mnt/SambaFiles cifs username=tom,password=foo,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

However, each time I reboot Box B, I have to do 'sudo mount -a' to mount the file directory of Box A.

Is it possible to automate it to avoid mounting it with every reboot? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if systemd can get you out of this problem.

Change this:

> //192.168.1.10/SambaSharedDirectory /mnt/SambaFiles cifs
>   username=tom,password=foo,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
>   0 0

To this:

> //192.168.1.10/SambaSharedDirectory /mnt/SambaFiles cifs
>   username=tom,password=foo,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,**noauto,x-systemd.automount**
>   0 0

By adding **noauto,x-systemd.automount** to your list of options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that the network is available when you try to mount the cifs share. So you should use the _netdev option in your fstab file.

From the man-pages of the mount command:

> _netdev:
>     The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent the system from attempting to mount these filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system).